# "AccessTokenRefreshError: Invalid Response 403" from oauth2client

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I am creating a script that will download all files for a particular Google Apps user by using a service account that is impersonates that user (using the Python template code provided [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) (see code block below).

```
def createDriveService(user_email):
  """Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts
  that act on behalf of the given user.

  Args:
    user_email: The email of the user.
  Returns:
    Drive service object.
  """
f = file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key,
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', prn=user_email)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
```

I have been able to successfully authenticate using this function, and can perform downloads, file list requests, etc. However, if I try to perform more than four downloads in a short period of time, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   // snip //
  File "C:\***\changeScan2.py", line 48, in createDriveService
    return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\apiclient\discovery.py", line 193, in build
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 405, in new_request
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 573, in _refresh
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 629, in _do_refresh_request
oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: Invalid response 403
```

The program successfully gets a list of files to download (files.list), downloads four files (authenticating each time), and then on the fifth download it provides the above error. The entire process takes 5-10 seconds. In multiple runs with different files, the program returns an error in the process of downloading the fifth file.

I trimmed the app down to the bare essentials, tried downloading different files, and received the same error. I tried catching exceptions and implementing exponential backoff for my createDriveService function, but the error seems to be in the Google API client files so I haven't been able to mitigate it. [Here's](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client-pysrc.html) a link to view the code for the oauth2client\client.py that seems to be giving me the problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the APIs Console where you got the private key for the SignedJwtAssertionCredentials there is also an API key at the bottom of that page. Pass that API key in as the developerKey parameter to the discovery.build() function:

http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/apiclient.discovery-module.html#build

The 403 response is returned when you reach the limit of your quota, either a total daily limit, or a short term limit. Since Drive comes with a daily courtesy quota limit of 500,000 requests per day I don't think you are hitting that limit, but you probably need to add that API key so that you get actually get that full quota.

I have recently committed a change to the client library so that 403 errors are handled better, this isn't in the released version yet, but if you pull from head you will actually see the 403 as an exception that should  will the full information about why the call failed.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the answer! I tried the API key and the most recent version of the client library from mercurial, and I'm getting an identical error (different code lines) - using the code section above as a model, the new error lines are 121, 195 (in discovery.py), 121, 433, 600, and 656 - culminating in the same Invalid response 403 error.

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.